# New passport but visa is in old (lost) passport

Tags: visas, passports, ethiopian-citizens

I had a Ethiopian passport with my permanent resident Canada visa stuck in it, but I lost it. Now I have a new passport. Will they allow me to board a flight with my new Ethiopian passport without any visa in it? I have my valid Canada resident card.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. You don't even need a passport to enter Canada as long as you have your PR card.

Comment: Probably better to cite a source: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/entry-requirements-country.html

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html

Comment: In the post, not a comment...